# How to do a looping to add new ComboBox base on it ItemsSource?

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I've make my ComboBox at code behind and its a looping. its like whenever user select item in the current comboBox it will add the comboBox. its inside a function called `DropDownClosed`.

```
ComboBox comboBox = new ComboBox();
comboBox.ItemsSource = menu.ToList();
comboBox.DropDownClosed += ComboBox_DropDownClosed;  
stackPanel.Children.Add(comboBox);
```

I want it to add new combobox (based on how many menu inside the `ItemsSource`) Let's say it have 5 menu inside `menu.ToList()` so it will repeat for 5 time. currently it will add infinity number of it.

how can I do that ?

and If possible I want something like this.

let says, inside the menu there are 5 menu which is

```
burger
fries
hotdog
bread
chicken
```

if for the first combobox the user select chicken then the second combobox(added dynamically by looping) does not have `chicken` as it items anymore(or else disable to click might do as well) and it continue until the menu all selected.

is it possible to do it ?

Comment: Sure. Have one (1) “data source” for all the combo boxes. Then, each time the user clicks on a combo box, “filter” out the selected item(s) in the previous combo box(s) and so on. Looping through each combo boxes items list and “physically” removing each item(s) is risky and unnecessary.

Comment: @JohnG yes I'm using 1 dataSource for all since it will loop the code I've made above. but how can I get the selected item from the previous one ? since it only have 1 code for combobox ? sorry for asking many question. I'm quite new to this

Comment: I can only assume each combo box will have a “unique” name… to get its value would be something like `value = comboBox1.Text`. You should clarify how many “different” combo boxes are you using. In addition, as I mentioned previously, I encourage you to “filter” each combo box as opposed to “adding/removing’ individual items from each combo box list. Try something and post what doesn’t work.

Comment: @JohnG yes I know how to do it if there is many difference combobox. the things is now I have only one code to generate the combobox and its a looping. its impossible for me to give the unique name for them. anyways thanks for your time.

Comment: Your comment… _”its impossible for me to give the unique name for them”_ … are you sure about that? There are too many questions. What happens if the user changes the same combo box twice? Are you disabling the combo box once selected? The posted code simply adds a new combo box with the menu list… how are you currently handling this “remove” the selected item on the next combo box as you describe? As stated earlier, if all the combo boxes use the same data source, you are going to have problems if you “remove” one of the items from that data source. A filter should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this still if u wanna modify the `ItemsSource` cmbs u can assign from allCmbx based on ur needs

```
List<ComboBox> allCmbx = new List<ComboBox>();
        List<string> allItems = new List<string> { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" };
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


            ComboBox comboBox = new ComboBox();
            comboBox.ItemsSource = allItems;
            comboBox.DropDownClosed += ComboBox_DropDownClosed;
            stackPanel.Children.Add(comboBox);
            allCmbx.Add(comboBox);


        }

        private void ComboBox_DropDownClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            ComboBox mainComboBox = (ComboBox)sender;
            mainComboBox.DropDownClosed -= ComboBox_DropDownClosed;
            ComboBox comboBox = new ComboBox();
            allItems.Remove(mainComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString());
            comboBox.ItemsSource = allItems;
            comboBox.DropDownClosed += ComboBox_DropDownClosed;
            stackPanel.Children.Add(comboBox);
            allCmbx.Add(comboBox);
        }
```

Comment: I've a problem with the  `allItems.Remove` since my `ItemsSource` which is `menu` come from this `var menu = menuBO.GetMenu(Menu2).Select(s => s.MenuName);` its does not contains definitions for `Remove`

Comment: @thatxx did u try .`Tolist().Remove()`?